# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, array given in

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run the following query

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM user_info JOIN Notifications ON user_info.user_info_id =Notifications.Sender_id AND Notifications.STATE=0 LIMIT 1";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$message=''

if($num_rows > 0){
    $con=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    switch ($con['Notification_Type']){
        case'events':
            $var="Notifications".$con['user_info_id'];
            $sql_shown="SELECT *FROMevent WHERE event.notification_shown = 0 AND event.user_info_id='$var'LIMIT 1";
            $query_vi=mysqli_query($con,$sql_shown);
            $num_rows_vi=mysqli_num_rows($query_vi);
            $message.=$con['Sender_id']."has created a Event";
            echo $message;
        break;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, array given in

This is my user table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info(
    user_info_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    u_first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    u_last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    u_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    u_mobile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    role ENUM('1yearM','1yearN','1yearR','1yearU','1yearS','2M','2R','2N','2U','2S','3M','3R','3N','3U','3S','4M','4R','4N','4U','4S','professor','librarian','admission_department') NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    u_ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    signup_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    last_login DATETIME NOT NULL,
    act_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    activation enum('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (user_info_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (u_email,u_mobile)
)
```

This is my event table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Event(
    Event_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Event_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Event_location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Event_Organizer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
    Event_Date_Posted DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Event_Starting_timings DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Event_Ending_timings DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Event_Day VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Event_Description text NOT NULL,
    Event_file_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Event_file_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Event_file_size VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_info_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    notification_shown ENUM('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (Event_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_info_id) REFERENCES user_info(user_info_id)    
)
```

This is my notification table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notifications(
    Notifications_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Notification_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Notification_Content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Notification_Created_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Notification_State ENUM('read','unread') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unread',
    Is_Notification_Delete ENUM('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    Notification_Deleted_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Sender_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    STATE ENUM('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    Recipient_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Notifications_id)  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite your `$con` variable with this line:

```
$con=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Before that line your `$con` variable was a valid MySQLi connection handle. After that line it is not an array. Therefore your `mysqli_query()` call complain that the first argument isn't a `mysqli` connection/object/handle anymore, but instead is now an array (which it shouldn't).

Change your `$con=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` so it doesn't overwrite your `$con` variable with the MySQLi connection/object/handle, but instead  write the result in a different variable (maybe `$userinfo`?).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `$con` it's been created with properly method `mysqli_connect('')`.